# Problems with function generator

Tags: java, runtime-error

Compilator don't have any errors but after the program starts I see white window and when I do interactions with the elements I start to see the program created in apache netbeans:

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class javaP extends JFrame {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TrigGraphsApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // Tworzenie panelu wyboru funkcji
        JPanel functionPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel functionLabel = new JLabel("Funkcja:");
        String[] functions = { "sin", "cos", "tg", "ctg", "arcsin", "arccos", "arctg", "arcctg" };
        JComboBox<String> functionComboBox = new JComboBox<>(functions);
        functionPanel.add(functionLabel);
        functionPanel.add(functionComboBox);
        
        // Tworzenie panelu parametrów
        JPanel parameterPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel amplitudeLabel = new JLabel("Amplituda:");
        JTextField amplitudeTextField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel phaseShiftLabel = new JLabel("Przesunięcie fazowe:");
        JTextField phaseShiftTextField = new JTextField(10);
        parameterPanel.add(amplitudeLabel);
        parameterPanel.add(amplitudeTextField);
        parameterPanel.add(phaseShiftLabel);
        parameterPanel.add(phaseShiftTextField);
        
        // Tworzenie przycisku rysowania
        JButton drawButton = new JButton("Rysuj");
        drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String selectedFunction = (String) functionComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                double amplitude = Double.parseDouble(amplitudeTextField.getText());
                double phaseShift = Double.parseDouble(phaseShiftTextField.getText());
                
                // Tworzenie panelu wykresu
                GraphPanel graphPanel = new GraphPanel(selectedFunction, amplitude, phaseShift);
                graphPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
                
                // Tworzenie okna wykresu
                JFrame graphFrame = new JFrame(selectedFunction + " Graph");
                graphFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                graphFrame.getContentPane().add(graphPanel);
                graphFrame.pack();
                graphFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                graphFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        // Dodawanie komponentów do głównego panelu
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(functionPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(parameterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(drawButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        // Dodawanie głównego panelu do ramki
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GraphPanel extends JPanel {
    private String function;
    private double amplitude;
    private double phaseShift;
    
    public GraphPanel(String function, double amplitude, double phaseShift) {
        this.function = function;
        this.amplitude = amplitude;
        this.phaseShift = phaseShift;
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        
        double xScale = width / (2 * Math.PI);
        double yScale = height / (2 * amplitude);
        
        double xOffset = width / 2;
        double yOffset = height / 2;
        
        double step = 0.01;
        
        for (double x = -2 * Math.PI; x < 2 * Math.PI; x += step) {
            double y;
            switch (function) {
                case "sin":
                    y = amplitude * Math.sin(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "cos":
                    y = amplitude * Math.cos(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "tg":
                    y = amplitude * Math.tan(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "ctg":
                    y = amplitude / Math.tan(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "arcsin":
                    y = amplitude * Math.asin(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "arccos":
                    y = amplitude * Math.acos(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "arctg":
                    y = amplitude * Math.atan(x - phaseShift);
                    break;
                case "arcctg":
                    y = amplitude * (Math.PI / 2 - Math.atan(x - phaseShift));
                    break;
                default:
                    y = 0;
            }
            
            int xPixel = (int) (x * xScale + xOffset);
            int yPixel = (int) (-y * yScale + yOffset);
            
            g2d.drawLine(xPixel, yPixel, xPixel, yPixel);
        }
    }
}
```

and this errors codes:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "this.wybranaFunkcja" is null
    at dawca.App.drawFunkcjaPlot(App.java:122)
    at dawca.App$5.paintComponent(App.java:78)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5271)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedFPScales(RepaintManager.java:1707)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1616)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2003)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3949)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because "this.wybranaFunkcja" is null
    at dawca.App.drawFunkcjaPlot(App.java:122)
    at dawca.App$5.paintComponent(App.java:78)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5271)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedFPScales(RepaintManager.java:1707)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1616)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2003)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3949)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Program should generate graphic functions `cos`, `sin`, `tan`, `ctan`, `arccos`, `arcsin`, `arctan`, `arcctan` and give option to change amplitude of functions and move function in x dimension and the program should start to generate after clicking the button.

Comment: Hello. You may be interested in reading "[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788)" and "[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code you provided is complete, but try to look for a place where you do

```
wybranaFunkcja.equals("string")
```

because aperantly wybranaFunkcja is null and that's why it is failing.
Then try to investigate why it is null, maybe it is not in the constructor or there a setter for it that is not being called.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the probable error